# Why does the following code trying to alias %>% from magrittr symbol fail?

Tags: r, magrittr

Why does the following code not work?

```
require(dplyr)
`%test%`<- `%>%`
mtcars %test% head
#Error in pipes[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

When the following works?

```
a <- function(x) x^2
a(4)
#[1] 16
b <- a
b(4)
#[1] 16
```

Why does this happen, and what needs to be done to make it work?

Comment: Interestingly, `\`%test%\` <- function(x,y)\`%>%\`(x,y)` works.

Comment: It seems that `%>%` tests if the function matches "%>%" with `is_pipe` and in `%test%`<- `%>%` it does not. E.g. " `%myop%` = function(x, y) match.call(); `%myop2%` = `%myop%`; `%myop3%` = function(x, y) x %myop% y " and call each: `"lhs" %myop% "rhs"; "lhs" %myop2% "rhs"; "lhs" %myop3% "rhs"`

Answer (score 7):

As alexis_laz points out above it has to do with `magrittr:::is_pipe` explicitly checking for `%>%` in your expression and not finding it and subsequent logic falling apart in `%>%` because of that.

But why does `%>%` need to explicitly look for (self or other) `%>%` in the call?

If you look at the source code - the *first* `%>%` actually expands the full call and constructs the expression that doesn't have any more pipes and eval's that expression. So the actual `%>%` operator only gets called once in a pipe, and `a %>% b %>% c` is converted in that first call directly to `c(b(a))` which then gets eval'd (as opposed to being converted first to `b(a) %>% c`).

It's not obvious to me that this has efficiency savings, so could be something more basic like keeping track of the `.` more easily when doing everything at once.